# Можно ли вставлять элементы в vector в цикле

Tags: c++, алгоритм, vector, итераторы

Есть последовательность из чисел, надо перед каждым отрицательным вставить 0
Я записал начальную последовательность в `vector` и потом хотел проставить в цикле 0 перед отрицательными, используя итератор, но мне выдало "can't increment vector iterator past end"

```cpp
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    vector<int>::iterator p;

    int x;
    //запись последовательность в вектор
    do
    {
        cin >> x;
        v.push_back(x);
    } while(x != 0);
    //вставка 0
    for (p = v.begin(); p != v.end(); p++)
    {
        if (*p < 0)
            v.insert(p, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Итератор p становится невалидным после вставки, поэтому надо так `p = v.insert(p, 0) + 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Итераторы в общем случае становятся не валидными после позиции вставки элемента. А если происходит перераспределение памяти у вектора, то и итераторы до позиции вставки также становятся не валидными, что имеет место в случае вашего цикла, который в противном случае может даже стать бесконечным.

Если вы еще пока не используете алгоритмы, то ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как можно выполнить поставленную задачу, используя только циклы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, -1, 2, 3, -4 };

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    size_t n = 0;

    for ( const auto &item : v ) n += item < 0;

    v.reserve( v.size() + n );

    for ( auto it = std::begin( v ); it != std::end( v ); ++it )
    {
        if ( *it < 0 ) ++( it = v.insert( it, 0 ) );
    }

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
1 -1 2 3 -4 
1 0 -1 2 3 0 -4
```

Если вам предложение

```
if ( *it < 0 ) ++( it = v.insert( it, 0 ) );
```

кажется слишком вычурным, то вы можете заменить его на

```
if ( *it < 0 )
{ 
    it = v.insert( it, 0 );
    ++it;
}
```